# Is it possible to know which method will get call while working with xcode simulator?

Tags: xcode, methods, ios-simulator

I am working/testing my application in xcode simulator. Is it possible to know which method in my code is called while pressing tabs, cells, navigation buttons or etc in xcode simulator?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Only if you set it up yourself, either by setting breakpoints throughout or by placing NSLog statements at the various points.

Comment: No way without this!!!!!!!  For setting breakpoints or placing NSLog also i need to know about the function calling.... :( Otherwise i need to place NSLog in all methods of my whole code?!?!?!?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way.